# search builder fails with date field in localized civicrm instance

Tags: search-builder, dates

My CiviCRM instance (4.6.11 embedded in Drupal 7.41 in Google cloud) is localized for French language with date format dd/mm/yyyy (31/12/2009). When using a date field in search builder, comparison is made to dates in yyyymmdd format and so gives wrong answers. Can we get search builder to use another date format or is it a known bug ?
Thanks for help.

Jean-Pierre

Added 03/24/2016 : I make a test in the civicrm demo site and it appears that the problem is not from localization but from membership. I want to list contacts with membership ending before a given date, and wathever date or operator you give for the Expiration Date, you allways get ALL the contacts.
Seems to be the same issue that https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/search-builder-date-results